# Erlang start application in production

Tags: erlang, rebar

When I'm testing my erlang application on localhost, I have a script that starts the server that looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
PWD="$(pwd)"
NAME="$(basename $PWD)"
erl -pa "$PWD/ebin" deps/*/ebin -boot start_sasl \
    -name devnode@127.0.0.1 \
    -s reloader \
    -s $NAME \
    -setcookie some_random_cookie \
    +K true \
    +P 65536
```

This prompts open the Erlang shell and from there I would type something like:

`application:start(myapp)`

This is fine for development purposes, but how do I deploy this in production? As of right now, the only way I can think of doing this is by starting a screen process and detaching from it. I don't think that should be the case. I am using rebar, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a custom boot script.  A boot script tells the erlang system what to start.  In the script you're using, you're setting the boot script with:

```
-boot start_sasl
```

http://www.erlang.org/doc/system_principles/system_principles.html, look for the section "User-Defined Boot Scripts"

An easier option may be to convert your application to use rebar:  https://github.com/basho/rebar.  You would then be able to do the following:

```
./rebar compile generate
```

This will create a release for the application, allowing you to then:

```
./rel/<app_name>/bin/<app_name>
```

Same principles, just all wrapped up for easy use.

Comment: Note that he already mentions that rebar is being used. Your answer would be a lot better if you explained how to write a rebar reltool.config.

Answer (score 5):

Add the parameter `-detached`. The [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) summarizes this nicely:

> Starts the Erlang runtime system detached from the system console. Useful for running daemons and backgrounds processes.

Once you do that, you can get your application to start with the `-s` parameter. Assuming `$NAME` = `myapp`, init will attempt to call `myapp:start/0` (you can customize this if you want). That function should end with a call to `application:start(myapp)`.

If you can get all of those puzzle pieces in place, you should have a working script.

Answer (score -8):

Well, you could try hooking it in to Apache [(see here)](http://21ccw.blogspot.com/2008/03/apache-erlang-for-dynamic-web-content.html), or a simple solution that's not quite as hacky as screen sessions is to use [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup). If you're actually implementing this on a production server, and don't want to take the Apache route, you might consider an [init script](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442412-managing-linux-daemons-with-init-scripts).

Comment: What does Apache have to do with anything here? My Erlang nodes do not run a web server.

Comment: Ah, based on the information you provided to the script I assumed it was behaving as a webserver, but I guess it could also just be interacting with another web server. In that case apache is less helpful ;) `nohup` is still a good solution, although using the `-detached` option as otherwise mentioned is probably better.

Comment: -1. A confusing answer.  Apache has nothing to do with it, and nohup is not necessary for a detached erlang node.