# start erlang application from command line

Tags: erlang, rebar

I have an erlang application, compiled with rebar.

Normally I start it with like this:

```
application:start(myapp).
```

from inside the erl shell.

Could anyone tell me how to start it like a normal command line program?

Comment: Some of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7032665/113848) might help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do:

```
erl -pa ebin -eval "application:start(myapp)"
```

If you want it to run in the background, add `-noshell -detached`

Comment: In my codes, I have 'application:get_env()' in start function and I got {badmatch, undefined} error returned by using -eval "application:start(myapp)". Is there any other library path I should include like '-pa'?

Comment: Oh, I answer my self question above. If you want to get some environment variable which is define in 'etc/app.confg', don't forget to include it by using '-config etc/app.config'.

Answer (score 8):

Create shell script, something like that:

```
exec erl -pa ebin/ deps/*/ebin -s myapp
```

Other options which you need see http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html.

Comment: {"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{cc,start,[],[]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Comment: for `erl -s myapp` to work you need to write a function in your myapp.erl as `start() -> application:start(myapp).` -s option is to call the MFA. By default it calls start without passing parameters if only module name is specified.